# How do I add multiple instances of Javascript Audio Player in static HTML site?

Tags: javascript, audio-player

I am working on a static portfolio site and have styled some Javascript audio players.
The site is live [here](https://jsomerset.uk) with the first audio player working almost exactly as desired (except the progress bar displays at the top of the div, I'd like it at the bottom). A photo is attached of the desired visual outcome.

[image]

I need **five** total audio players. How can I achieve this?

Current Javascript:

```
const audioPlayer = document.querySelector(".audio-player");
const audio = new Audio(
    "https://jsomerset.uk/images/victory.mp3"
);

console.dir(audio);

audio.addEventListener(
    "loadeddata",
    () => {
        audioPlayer.querySelector(".time .length").textContent = getTimeCodeFromNum(
            audio.duration
        );
        audio.volume = .75;
    },
    false
);

const timeline = audioPlayer.querySelector(".timeline");
timeline.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const timelineWidth = window.getComputedStyle(timeline).width;
    const timeToSeek = e.offsetX / parseInt(timelineWidth) * audio.duration;
    audio.currentTime = timeToSeek;
}, false);

setInterval(() => {
    const progressBar = audioPlayer.querySelector(".progress");
    progressBar.style.width = audio.currentTime / audio.duration * 100 + "%";
    audioPlayer.querySelector(".time .current").textContent = getTimeCodeFromNum(
        audio.currentTime
    );
}, 500);

const playBtn = audioPlayer.querySelector(".controls .toggle-play");
playBtn.addEventListener(
    "click",
    () => {
        if (audio.paused) {
            playBtn.classList.remove("play");
            playBtn.classList.add("pause");
            audio.play();
        } else {
            playBtn.classList.remove("pause");
            playBtn.classList.add("play");
            audio.pause();
        }
    },
    false
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code can't run properly, since you're selecting non existent elements.
Check you dev tools console for errors.

E.g. you're trying to display the current time in an element with the class `time` – but yout html does not contain such an element.

Besides, you haven't defined the method `getTimeCodeFromNum()`.

See the cleaned up code – not usable blocks are commented out :

```js
const audioPlayer = document
  .querySelectorAll(".audio-player")
  .forEach((audioPlayer) => {
    const audio = new Audio(audioPlayer.dataset.src);
    //console.dir(audio);


    /*
    audio.addEventListener(
      "loadeddata",
      () => {
        audioPlayer.querySelector(
          ".time .length"
        ).textContent = getTimeCodeFromNum(audio.duration);
        audio.volume = 0.75;
      },
      false
    );
    */


    const timeline = audioPlayer.querySelector(".timeline");
    timeline.addEventListener(
      "click",
      (e) => {
        const timelineWidth = window.getComputedStyle(timeline).width;
        const timeToSeek =
          (e.offsetX / parseInt(timelineWidth)) * audio.duration;
        audio.currentTime = timeToSeek;
      },
      false
    );


    setInterval(() => {
      const progressBar = audioPlayer.querySelector(".progress");
      progressBar.style.width =
        (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100 + "%";
      /*
      audioPlayer.querySelector(
        ".time .current"
      ).textContent = getTimeCodeFromNum(audio.currentTime);
      */
    }, 500);


    const playBtn = audioPlayer.querySelector(".controls .toggle-play");
    playBtn.addEventListener(
      "click",
      () => {
        if (audio.paused) {
          playBtn.classList.remove("play");
          playBtn.classList.add("pause");
          audio.play();
        } else {
          playBtn.classList.remove("pause");
          playBtn.classList.add("play");
          audio.pause();
        }
      },
      false
    );

    /*
    audioPlayer
      .querySelector(".volume-button")
      .addEventListener("click", () => {
        const volumeEl = audioPlayer.querySelector(".volume-container .volume");
        audio.muted = !audio.muted;
        if (audio.muted) {
          volumeEl.classList.remove("icono-volumeMedium");
          volumeEl.classList.add("icono-volumeMute");
        } else {
          volumeEl.classList.add("icono-volumeMedium");
          volumeEl.classList.remove("icono-volumeMute");
        }
      });
      */
  });
```

```css
body {
  background: #000
}

.audio-player {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 6px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100vw;
  color: #efefef;
}

.timeline {
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 5px;
}

.progress {
  background: #efefef;
  width: 0%;
  height: 5px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
}

.controls * {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.play {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid #0000;
  border-left: 13px solid white;
}

.pause {
  height: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.pause:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  height: 15px;
  width: 3px;
}

.pause:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 9px;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  height: 15px;
  width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="audio-player a-one font" data-src="https://jsomerset.uk/images/swain.mp3">
  <div class="timeline">
    <div class="progress" style="width: 0%;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="name">Action</div>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="play-container">
      <div class="toggle-play play">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="audio-player a-two font" data-src="https://jsomerset.uk/images/victory.mp3">
  <div class="timeline">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="name">Victory Song</div>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="play-container">
      <div class="toggle-play play">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are a real life hero :) it's working almost perfectly now, thanks so much!! The third audio player doesn't play the correct audio, but other than that it functions as intended! [link](https://jsomerset.uk)

Comment: 3rd and second players share **the same mp3 URL:** "https://jsomerset.uk/images/victory.mp3" - I guess just a typo. Fixing the URLs should solve the problem.

Comment: yes you're right.. solved now. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelectorAll`, then loop over the selection. You can store the mp3 URL for each div inside a `data-src` attribute:

```html
<div class="audio-player" data-src="https://jsomerset.uk/images/victory.mp3">...</div>
<div class="audio-player" data-src="https://jsomerset.uk/images/anotherFile.mp3">...</div>
<div class="audio-player" data-src="https://jsomerset.uk/images/etc.mp3">...</div>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".audio-player").forEach(audioPlayer => {
    const audio = new Audio(audioPlayer.dataset.src);

    // rest of your code
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I don't think I have implemented it correctly, I get an error "parsing error: the keyword 'const' is reserved" - I've published changes so you can see it live on the same URL. Thanks again @moonwave99